# Restrict displayed products by author in WooCommerce backend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to show the WooCommerce products by a user who added those products from admin.

For example:

1. user1 logs into the wp-admin and add product A, B, C into a system.
2. user2 logs into the wp-admin and add product D, E, F into a system.

Then at current user1 is able to see user2 products in wp-admin and user2 can see user1 products.

I want to customize the product list in admin in such a way that
*Admin can see all the products* and *user1 can see only his products* and user2 can see his products.

I am new to WooCommerce, so please help.

Comment: you may need to go for multi-vendor plugins, where we can create multiple vendor users, each vendors can work on their own products only.

Comment: No i don't want to go for multi vendor plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function exclude_other_author_products($query) {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if (in_array('administrator', $current_user->roles))
        return $query;
    if ($query->query['post_type'] == 'product' && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set('author__in', $current_user->ID);
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_other_author_products');
```

Comment: I would like to know where i can read how to customise these things so that in future before posting here i would have tried to do something by my self

Comment: Modify your answer because you used variable as an function $current_user

Comment: Replace "author__in" with "author" ...
"author__in" is deprecated, use only "author" to avoid errors

Answer (score -1):

You may need to go for multi vendor plugins. Where each vendor can create and manage their own products.

Here is the most popular multi vendor plugins for WooCommerce.

- Dokan Multivendor Marketplace
- WC Vendors Pro
- WC Marketplace
- YITH Multivendor
- WooCommerce Product Vendors

Comment: I am not building the UI for these vendors, i am creating an app where i will show all the products from these vendors, so i think these plugins would not provide the API support

Comment: I want to make a system like vendors added their products and all the products will be listing on the app, customer purchases the product and commission will be sent to admin but no vendor specific shop page.